# How to map function on each element with css class in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, initialization, selectors-api

I'm rewriting some stuff which I created with jQuery to vanilla JS. I can't find vanilla JS equivalent for mapping my function to all elements with specified CSS class. For example I have function for slider, in jQuery I'm mapping it like this:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.slider = function() {
        this.each(function() {
            // Do some stuff
        });
    };

    $('.slider').slider();

}(jQuery));
```

What is the propper way to do it in vanilla JS?

Comment: You can choose `document.querySelectorAll` or `document.getElementsByClassName`, but the latter returns a HTMLCollection so it will not allow you to use NodeList.prototype.forEach().

Comment: [You might not need jQuery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#each) has a useful list of vanilla JS alternatives for jQuery functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement e.g. a function `initializeSlider` which accepts an element-node parameter and do whatever has to be done with such a node.

Query a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) of all `.slider` classified element-nodes via e.g. [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and execute the slider related function [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) of the node-list's node-items.

```
                                      // (function($) {
                                      //
                                      //   $.fn.slider = function() {
function initializeSlider(elmNode) {  //     this.each(function() {
  // Do some stuff with/to `elmNode`  //       // Do some stuff
}                                     //     });
document                              //   };
  .querySelectorAll('.slider')        //
  .forEach(initializeSlider);         //   $('.slider').slider();
                                      //
                                      // }(jQuery));
```